# NSPF abbreviation

Tags: abbreviations

I am looking at some US statistics and I have found this abbreviation, with this [explanation](http://www.afsc.noaa.gov/Publications/AFSC-TM/NOAA-TM-AFSC-66.pdf) (pdf) in the subtext.

> NSPF - Not specifically provided for.

The context is a [list of US trading codes](http://www.st.nmfs.noaa.gov/st1/trade/build_a_database/ProductsTables.html).

> 0304991012 GROUNDFISH COD NSPF MEAT FROZEN > 6.8KG

I could not find a better description on the internet, so I am asking you what meaning you give "not specifically provided for".

Comment: The phrase seems quite self-explanatory to me. What specifically is confusing you?

Comment: I am not a native English speaker and for me is not. What is not provided for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you may use the trading code, but only when there is no other trading code that more closely matches the commodity.

Other ways of expressing “not specifically provided for”:

- not elsewhere specified or indicated
- miscellaneous
- uncategorized
- catch-all
- other

Comment: So, if you had >6.8KG of Frozen Haddock instead of Cod, and there wasn't a specific code for Frozen Haddock, then you could use this code instead.

Comment: It would not be right to use the catch-all code for frozen cod if (i) what you produce is not cod, or (ii) what you produce is a closer match to a different code that that describes a specific frozen cod product.

It complicates matters that haddock is sometimes called cod and  sold as cod.

Comment: Actually there is a lot of NSPF for haddock as well. I guess, as @MetaEd was saying, that this is intended for whatever cannot be more precisely put in other categories. The strange thing is the volumes of NSPF present in this taxonomy, compared with others, which have a tree system and you have special container for "others". The confusion is mine. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Which is why I said "and there wasn't a specific code for Frozen Haddock," then you should use the one for cod or some other groundfished fish.

Comment: Perfectly localized.